# KDB+ / Q unique random values with variable for amount

Tags: random, kdb, q-lang

I am quite new to KDB+ and have a question about generating random numbers.

Lets say I want to create **num** random unique numbers.

When i use this

```
q)10?10
q)-10?10
```

I get 10 random numbers in line 1 and 10 unique random numbers in line 2 (*range from 0 to 9*)

When I want to introduce a variable like this

```
q)num:10
q)num?10  / works
q)-num?10 / dont work
```

The generation of unique randoms does not work.

**Whats the correct syntax for this?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you num unique numbers between 0 and 9.

```
q)(neg num)?10
```

Comment: okay, this seems to work fine for some datatypes. 

But what about this


`q)(neg num)?2001.01.01`

Comment: The distinct does not work with dates.
    `q)-10?2001.01.01
    'type`
try adding distinct numbers to a date if you are looking for distinct dates.

Comment: date is an integer under the hood. So you can convert any sane integer to a date after randomising however many you want

Comment: okay, thanks very much. didnt think of using distinct number addition and casting.